# Sandbox: Testing in app purchase issue (no products retrieved from app store connect)

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, sandbox, testflight

All of a sudden, I am no longer able to test in app purchases on testflight builds.

try await Product.products(for: [productID])
returns an empty array.

Production (app in app store) functions just fine. But when I test the release build of the production version or any other versions, the fetch returns an empty array. This seems to be a sandbox issue.

The ID is correct, Tax and banking forms are valid... This isnt the first release with in-app purchase or subscriptions so I am not sure why I am having this sandbox issue.